# get the values of two dropdowns into a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have two dropdowns that I need their values inside a URL. I am using selectize for the two dropdowns. But I mostly used jquery for the functions.

Expected output is a URL that changes with value of the two dropdowns after the user clicks on the button.
when I checked the value of the URL after the click event it doesn't show both on the URL instead it occurs differently I believe as it should but is there a way to make these values appear on the url together at once?

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".dropdown_menu").selectize({
    sortField: "text",
    placeholder: "Select a value...",
  });

  $("#dad").on("click", function() {
    $(".dropdown_menu").map(function() {
      let marketValues = "";
      let msmValues = "";
      if ($(this).is("#dropdown1")) {
        //using join "&" to capture multiple values   
        marketValues += $(this).val().join("&");
      }
      if ($(this).is("#dropdown2")) {
        msmValues += $(this).val().join("&");
      }
      //expecting the url change with values of the dropdown after the click event
      let url = `localhost:5000/${marketValues}/${msmValues}`;

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.14.0/js/selectize.min.js"></script>
<!-- food Drop down menu -->
<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <select id="dropdown1" class="dropdown_menu" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="rice">rice</option>
    <option value="beans">beans</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- name dropdown -->
<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <select id="dropdown2" class="dropdown_menu" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="bob">bob</option>
    <option value="max">max</option>
  </select>
</div>



<button id="dad">send</button>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - what is the EXPECTED output? Why use .map instead of .each and where is the loop over selected values and why do you join with "&" ?

Comment: I am using join "&" because the user has the ability to select multiple values from the dropdown so it other to get this values on the server side I use the join method. the expected output is the URL. so the URL changes relative to the selected values. any changes in the dropdown should give a new url result

Comment: You should not use & but ,

Comment: Please post HTML!

Comment: have posted the html

Comment: [I have answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73969184/295783) it is much simpler than your think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside of the map loop declare your variables **url**, **marketValues** and **msmValues**. Then After the loop, generate the URL with the variables. Right now, the URL gets replaced during each loop as well as the other two variables. Also, use an else if not two separate if statements.

Using each is the better option as map is used to apply functions to the content of the array. Where as each simply loops through them

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".dropdown_menu").selectize({
    sortField: "text",
    placeholder: "Select a value...",
  });

  $("#dad").on("click", function() {
    let marketValues = "";
    let msmValues = "";

    $(".dropdown_menu").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is("#dropdown1")) {
        //using join "&" to capture multiple values   
        marketValues += $(this).val().join("&");
      }
      else if ($(this).is("#dropdown2")) {
        msmValues += $(this).val().join("&");
      }
    });

    let url = `//localhost:5000/${marketValues}/${msmValues}`;
    console.log(url);
  });
});
```

Comment: There is no need concatenate

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop since you already have unique IDs

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".dropdown_menu").selectize({
    sortField: "text",
    placeholder: "Select a value...",
  });
  $("#dad").on("click", function() {
    let marketValues = $("#dropdown1").val().join("&"),
      msmValues = $("#dropdown2").val().join("&");
    //expecting the url change with values of the dropdown after the click event
    let url = `localhost:5000/${marketValues}/${msmValues}`;
    // do something with the URL here
    console.log(url)
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.14.0/css/selectize.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.14.0/js/selectize.min.js"></script>
<!-- food Drop down menu -->
<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <select id="dropdown1" class="dropdown_menu" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="rice">rice</option>
    <option value="beans">beans</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- name dropdown -->
<div style="max-width: 200px">
  <select id="dropdown2" class="dropdown_menu" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="bob">bob</option>
    <option value="max">max</option>
  </select>
</div>



<button id="dad">send</button>
```